# Чтение имени файла

Tags: c#

Всем привет, у меня есть код, который создает 254 файла

```
for (int i = 1; i < max_items; i++) {
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("Item");
    dir.Create();
    if (File.Exists( @ "Item\item" + i + ".dat") == false) {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream( @ "Item\item" + i + ".dat", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

        bw.Write("item" + i);
        bw.Write("");
        bw.Write("");
        bw.Write(0);
        bw.Write(0);

        bw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

Так вот теперь мне надо считать *имена* этих файлов и добавить их в ListBox, как такое сделать?

И как можно при помощи C# *переименовать* файл?

Comment: Ну вы же создаете файлы с именами `@"Item\item" + i + ".dat"` - что мешает просто добавлять в массив эту строку с заменой `i` на нужное число?

Comment: Извините, я не совсем понял что Вы имеете ввиду?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Путь может придётся подкорректировать

```
foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("Item\\"))//путь
{
    ListBox.Items.Add(file);
}
```

- [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx)
- [Directory Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx)
- [ListBox.ObjectCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add.aspx)

Comment: А скажите а можно чтобы ListBox выводил не путь, а только имя файла?

Comment: Чтобы в листбокс выводить только имя файла, можно сделать так:

    ListBox.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё работает как надо.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы переименовать файл используйте метод File.Move:

[C# Как переименовать файл?](http://dotnetways.com/hints/c-kak-pereimenovat-fayl/)